# Polymorphism in trait objects with associated types

Tags: rust, polymorphism, traits

I have a trait with a number of implementations that satisfy the common interface:

```rs
pub trait Schema<'a> {
    // ConfigTypes will be parsed from HTTP POST requests, but different
    // implementations can have different fields and know how to parse
    // themselves
    type ConfigType: rocket::request::FromForm<'a>
    fn configure(&mut self, cfg: Self::Configure);
    // and more...
}
```

Now imagine I want to implement a simple key/value store to map any number of these schemas from arbitrary strings. I feel like this should be possible with a HashMap, but what would the type be?

```rs
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Datastore<'a> {
    cache: HashMap<String, dyn Schema<'b>>
}
```

This fails complaining that the associated type `ConfigType` must be specified, but I want to store any implementation of `Schema` behind this cache!

I expected the problem is in irregular sizing, since the values of HashMap are expected to have static size. Alright then -- let's add Boxes to things.

```rs
// as above
struct Datastore<'a> {
    cache: HashMap<String, Box<dyn Schema<'b>>>
}
```

but alas -- the same error presents. How do I define this structure to be able to hold any Schema implementer?

Comment: I'd implement like this if I want to go with static dispatching: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=29bf42ff170247d69dc1d574355c2016

Comment: Suppose you could have `cache: HashMap<String, Box<dyn Schema<'a>>>`, without specifying `ConfigType`. Now: what are you going to do with that? You cannot call `configure` because, since `ConfigType` is erased, you don't know what type to pass to it.

Comment: @trent I expected that the inner type would know its own structure, but you're right that's rather silly.

Comment: @ÖmerErden I considered that, but that makes a single datastore only serve a single Schema implementation, right? My intention was to have arbitrary implementations behind the same datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associated type must be known. Otherwise how does the compiler know what type to use when you call methods that use that type?

There are a few ways around this:

1. You use `Box<dyn Schema<ConfigType = &dyn rocket::request::FromForm<'b>, 'b>`
   You might have to implement `rocket::request::FromForm<'b>` for `&dyn rocket::request::FromForm<'b>` so it can downcast and pass it to the correct type.
2. You just erase the whole type, and use `Box<dyn Any>`. Now you have to downcast it before you can use it.

Comment: ah passing the dynamic trait object down is a good idea. The callers will know what the correct type is so downcasting should be straightforward.